# Cloning OS X encrypted drive

Tags: macos, filevault

I've used `dd` on Linux to make a block for block bootable copy of a LUKS encrypted volume which created a bootable encrypted clone. I'm trying to achieve the same on a Filevault2 volume, `disk0` as internal disk. I want to write this to an identically sized partition on an external USB disk.

I made the destination partition a GUID Journaled extended HFS+ journaled to match the original volume. The `dd` finished but the partition is unusable, doesn't unlock, mount or boot.

I'm thinking of reformatting the partition as DOS and writing over it with `dd` again. Would it be safe to hope the partition will inherit the desired scheme from the source? It takes 4 hours to write 250GB and wanted to see if anyone else had done this before.

Filevault2 reconfigures the single partition on disk0, to add the recovery partition after 10.7 giving you something like this:

```
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1 
2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         249.2 GB   disk0s2 
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER 
0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *248.9 GB   disk1
```

`disk1` is the encrypted data of the core storage logical volume. This is similar to what happens in LUKS on Linux.

So my hope is to get this into a partition on a shared 1 TB external drive. Any thoughts on what format to make that partition would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please could you copy-paste Terminal output into a code block - one long line of output is very difficult to read.

Comment: OK, I've edited the output to be more readable...

Answer (score 1):

Just to rectify one thing: *disk1* is **not** the encrypted data. Disk1 is a mounted "virtual" volume with its own disk identifier. This volume is unlocked and as such unencrypted if you are a legitimate user. It's based on inferior encrypted data structures residing in disk0s2.

To clone (and subsequently decrypt) FileVault2 volumes successfully three objects/data structures are important:

1. Superior LVM structures in disk0s2 (the CoreStorage Volume Group)
2. The *Recovery HD* partition. It contains some intermediate keys which are necessary to extract the final keys to unlock the FileVault2 volume.
3. The encrypted data itself

To clone a FileVault2 volume you may either `dd` the CoreStorage LVG **and** the Recovery HD or copy the unlocked FileVault2 volume to a second volume with *rsync* or *Disk Utility*/a disk cloner like *Carbon Copy Cloner*.

**dd:**

1. Open Terminal and enter `diskutil list`.
2. Enter `sudo gpt -r -vv show /dev/diskX` with *diskX*: the disk with the CoreStorage LVG containing the FileVault2 Logical Family/Volume
3. Now attach a second (external) disk (*diskY*) and replicate the GUID partition table of the source (diskX) to the target disk (size, type etc.) with `gpt`.
4. Recheck the identity of the GUID partition table of diskX and diskY
5. Enter:
   `dd if=/dev/rdiskXs1 of=/dev/rdiskYs1` to copy the EFI partition
   `dd if=/dev/rdiskXs2 of=/dev/rdiskYs2` to copy the CoreStorage LVG
   `dd if=/dev/rdiskXs3 of=/dev/rdiskYs3` to copy the Recovery HD
6. done

**Disk Cloner**

This will not create an identical disk (same intermediate/final keys etc.) but a volume containing identical data.

1. Boot to a Recovery HD, an installer thumb drive or a second full-blown OS X volume.
2. Enter the unlock key of the FileVault2 volume while booting.
3. Attach the external disk and create a sufficiently dimensioned normal volume with an appropriate tool.
4. Open *Disk Utility* (or *Carbon Copy Cloner* if use a full OS X system)
5. Restore the source volume (the unlocked FileVault2 volume) to the destination disk.
6. Reboot to the external drive.
7. Open System Preferences -> Security and enable FileVault.

Comment: Should not `dd if=/dev/rdiskX of=/dev/rdiskY` replace steps 2..5 of dd variant?

Comment: I understand if the destination is smaller, but should not it work is destination is equal or bigger?

Comment: Small test of copying 4 partitions from a smaller ram disk to a bigger ram disk seems to move everything as expected

Comment: @tig You are right for most cases. But the usage of  `dd` is error prone - especially for non-pros. I prefer to publish the 1 partition to 1 partition `dd` command here. Think of an encrypted volume & Recovery HD **and** a subsequent BOOTCAMP partition or non-allocated disk space as source and a already partitioned disk with some free space (just enough space for the three partitions at the beginning of the target disk or in between).